# print pdf with no margins

Tags: cups, printing, imagemagick, lp

I have a small script that reads a mailbox and prints any attached pdf using cups lp. This is mostly for printing package labels. Some companies however supply a label with no margins which will be cropped when printed.

I'm printing on a brother hl2030 laser. I've tried looking a printer option that can be used for this but no luck. I also tried imagemagick tools convert or mogrify but in most cases produce a blank pdf. What is a good solution for this?

The lpoptions look like this: copies=1 device-uri=usb://Brother/HL-2030%20series?serial=D8J783163 finishings=3 job-cancel-after=10800 job-hold-until=no-hold job-priority=50 job-sheets=none,none marker-change-time=0 number-up=1 printer-commands=AutoConfigure,Clean,PrintSelfTestPage printer-info='Brother HL-2030 series' printer-is-accepting-jobs=true printer-is-shared=true printer-is-temporary=false printer-location printer-make-and-model='Brother HL-2030 Foomatic/hl1250 (recommended)' printer-state=3 printer-state-change-time=1696284916 printer-state-reasons=none printer-type=8564740 printer-uri-supported=ipp://localhost/printers/Brother_HL-2030_series

Comment: For an old solution using Ghostscript see this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27670586/5008284) answer and the script linked to in the *last* comment to that answer.